# RANK in SQL but start at 1 again when number is greater than

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I need an sql code for the below. I want it to RANK however if DSLR >= 60 then I want the rank to start again like below.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: sqlserver, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: How do you intend to preserver the original order of your `DSLR` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that defines the ordering of the rows, say `id`, you can address this as a gaps-and-islands problem. Islands are group of adjacent record that start with a `dslr` above `60`. We can identify them with a window sum, then rank within each island:

```
select dslr, rank() over(partition by grp order by id) as rn
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when dslr >= 60 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```